# How to pass tensor placeholder in for loop range?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to set the range of a for loop according to the input in my tensorflow graph:

```html
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[3, None])
videos_timesteps_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None])
....
for v_ind in range(batch_size):
    start = timesteps_placeholder[v_ind]
    end = timesteps_placeholder[v_ind+1]

    for t in range(start,end):
        ....
```

But I get the error: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
What can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace range with tf.range.
Example in tensorflow 2.x

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

@tf.function
def loop_tensor(start, end):
    for t in tf.range(start, end):
        print(t)
    
    
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[3, None])
videos_timesteps_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
for v_ind in range(3):
    start = videos_timesteps_placeholder[v_ind]
    end = videos_timesteps_placeholder[v_ind + 1]
    loop_tensor(start, end)
```